# Random image pulling from FB Album

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, slider

I'm trying to modify a jQuery script that draws Facebook photos by album ID.

It seems its only pulling the first image in the album.

How can i modify the "fetching" process to a random image and not sequential?

jQuery:

```
$.fn.fbPhotos = function(album, limit) {

    function base_append(obj) {
        $(base).append(obj);
    }

    function getPhoto(obj) {

        var id = obj.id;
        var img = obj.img;
        var link = obj.link;

        var wrap = $('<div></div>').attr({
            'class': 'fb-photo',
            'id': id
        });


        var avatar = new Image();
        avatar.src = img;

        var _avatar = $('<a></a>').attr('href', link).attr('target', '_blank').attr('class', 'avatar').html(avatar);

        $(wrap).append($(_avatar));
        return wrap;

    }

    function init() {
        fetch();
    }

    function fetch() {
        var r;
        var data = {};
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + albumId + '/photos?limit=' + topLimit,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: data,
            success: function(obj) {
                //    console.log(obj);
                if (obj.error) {
/*       var img = new Image();
                         img.src = theme_url + '/images/ico_fail_bird.png';
                         wipe(img); */
                    return false;
```

The rest on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2JjbV/43/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with the Graph API, but you can do it with the FQL [photo table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo). Change this line in your `fetch` function:

```
url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+src+FROM+photo+WHERE+album_object_id="' 
     + albumId + '"+ORDER+BY+rand()+LIMIT+' + topLimit,
```

Comment: Try it with the updated code above. Your returned object is different now, so you'll also need to change your display logic.